# The rendered input is acting as object rather than string in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, search, searchqueryset

The rendered input is getting interpreted as word 'object' rather than text getting entered in input in React. So I have this API I want to search with input while I am searching it is getting written word 'object' rather than what am I writing.

Object is getting written instead of what I searched for

[image: 1]

Here I searched for input but again object is getting written in query

[image: 2]

```js
import { useState } from "react";

function () {
  const [endpoint, setEndpoint] = useState("");

  function searchChange(e) {
    setEndpoint(e.target.value);
    console.log(endpoint);

    const options = {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "X-RapidAPI-Key": "baef7285e6msh0aae02b3fd1dde5p1d01aajsne4c06de3d63f",
        "X-RapidAPI-Host": "spotify81.p.rapidapi.com",
      },
    };

    fetch(
      "https://spotify81.p.rapidapi.com/search?q=" +
        {endpoint} +
        "&type=albums&offset=0&limit=10&numberOfTopResults=5",
      options
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((response) => console.log(response))
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));
  }
  return (
    <input
      className="input"
      value={endpoint}
      placeholder="  Search"
      onChange={searchChange}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SA! Is it possible "object" is a word in the name property?

Comment: Please use [code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). What do you mean by _getting interpreted as word 'object' rather than text_. Are you getting the correct value from the `e.target.value` when checking the console.log?

Comment: @RubenSmn Yes I am getting the correct value while console logging. But I am not getting the result of the query I searched for instead I am getting result of word 'object'. So I think jsx is just interpreting my words as object instead of word itself

Comment: No its not a name property @Undo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When building your fetch URL you add `+{endpoint}+` which will result in a string with a `q` of `[object Object]`

```js
"https://spotify81.p.rapidapi.com/search?q=[object Object]&type=albums&offset=0&limit=10&numberOfTopResults=5";
```

The correct way to concatenate the fetch URL is the following, by removing the brackets `{}`

```js
"https://spotify81.p.rapidapi.com/search?q=" +
  endpoint +
  "&type=albums&offset=0&limit=10&numberOfTopResults=5";
```

Now this will fetch your `endpoint` but it will be one step (character) behind since setState is *sort of async* meaning your `endpoint` value inside the `searchChange` function will not get updated until the next render. You can fix this by directly using the `e.target.value` inside your URL.

```js
"https://spotify81.p.rapidapi.com/search?q=" +
  e.target.value +
  "&type=albums&offset=0&limit=10&numberOfTopResults=5";
```

Or using a `useEffect` for when the `endpoint` value changes

```js
useEffect(() => {
  fetch(
    "https://spotify81.p.rapidapi.com/search?q=" +
      endpoint +
      "&type=albums&offset=0&limit=10&numberOfTopResults=5",
    options
  )
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((response) => console.log(response))
    .catch((err) => console.error(err));
}, [endpoint]);
```

This way you can use the `endpoint` value in your fetch.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is properly formated, but I noticed that how you build the url is probably incorrect.

Right now I look like you always send `q={endpoint}` as a string and no the variable.

Try to change your fetch to this using string interpolation:

```js
fetch(`https://spotify81.p.rapidapi.com/search?q=${endpoint}&type=albums&offset=0&limit=10&numberOfTopResults=5`,
options)
```

Comment: Thanks but that only works if I have Harmony installed with React